# Chrome 61 and timeOrigin has just gone

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

I've just updated Chrome from 60 to 61 and performance.timeOrigin param disappeared.

Here is demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/82a3rbr0/

```
function run(fn) {
  return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['('+fn+')()'])));
}

const worker = run(function() {
  console.log("worker", performance.now(), performance.timeOrigin);
});

console.log("main", performance.now(), performance.timeOrigin);
```

Now we can't measure time independently. Tried to find some info about that change but have nothing.

Anyone knows why timeOrigin now is always undefined?

Comment: The function seems not to be shipped yet. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5695487386583040 and here: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/619246

Comment: @Doomenik, I was using it with success...

Comment: @ElSajko my install of chrome 60 (haven't updated yet) does not have that property in either workers or the main thread. Did you turn a flag on or something?

Comment: @ElSajko it was experimental so you probably activated a flag

Comment: @Doomenik, I don't remember sth like that. How I can enable it by flag again then?

Comment: Sry I don´t know just found on the ticket system for the last chrome version: "This CL adds performance.timeOrigin under an experimental flag. Definition:
https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-3/#dom-performance-timeorigin"

Comment: @ElSajko not sure you can. Stuff behind flags is not guaranteed to still be there on the next release. It's the equivalent of directly accessing private fields, do so at your own risk.

Comment: From what I can gather 'timeOrigin` is the same as `performance.timing.navigationStart`, so maybe you could replace with that.

Comment: @Keith, tried, but this param is only in main/dom thread, not in webworkers

Comment: Have switched to Date.now() for now, less accurate but works. Just need the same time from any thread/process of website.